# How to initiate for loop to run for a number of iteration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested, vectorization

sorry again for multiple silly questions in a day. I am very novice and do not know programming well. I have asked a simple question about for loop **here**, which has been sorted out:

[How to divide two different array in for loop matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918117/how-to-divide-two-different-array-in-for-loop-matlab/28918451#28918451)

I need to **initiate this for loop inside a number of iteration, say 10 000**, to get the output, where **result (1:15)./result (16:30) will be different** for every iteration. Meaning, for every iteration, result(u) variates. And I still need to bring out the **resultX(u) (the position)** output per iteration as well.

I have tried this with for loop. But it keep on giving me the same result for every iteration. I do not how to vectorized this too, which is worst. Please, I need help on this.

**Additional info grabbed from comments**

I need a matrix output `(row = iteration, column=u)`.

I want the variation of `u` value for every iteration, which is why I prompt the code below for every

```
u:acx = rand();
newacx = round(acx*100); 
if (newacx < 10 || newacx == 10)
    [valueone,positionone] = randomFunction(a); 
elseif (newacx > 10) 
    [valueone,positionone] = max(start(1,:));
end
```

Comment: I think this is an easily answerable question if you could provide a minimal example of what you're trying to do.  Make sure to include the input variables (even if its just the size/dimensions of them if you can't fit the actual data), and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Hi, @jedwards. I need a matrix output (row = iteration, column=u) . I want the variation of u value for every iteration, which is why I prompt the code below for every u ---> (`acx = rand(); newacx = round(acx*100);`) then the condition if else (`if (newacx < 10 || newacx == 10), [valueone,positionone] = randomFunction(a); elseif (newacx > 10), [valueone,positionone] = max(start(1,:)); end`). I hope this is explain your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
NUM_ITER = 10000;
out = zeros(NUM_ITER, 15);

for iter = 1:NUM_ITER
    start=zeros(2,15);
    a=[-12 10 -5 3 21 19 3 7 17 21];

    for u = 1:30  
        acx = rand();
        newacx = round(acx*100);

        if (newacx < 10 || newacx == 10)
           [valueone,positionone] = randomFunction(a); 
        elseif (newacx > 10)
           [valueone,positionone] = max(start(1,:));
        end

        result(u) = valueone;
        resultX(u)= positionone;
    end

    u = result(1:15)./result(16:30);

    out(iter,:) = u;
end

out         % Results of running NUM_ITER times
out(1,:)    % Results of first iteration
out(2,:)    % Results of second iteration
```

**Note** I really have no idea what you're doing in this script, but if I understand your question correctly, `out` should have what you're looking for -- it's a matrix of size (`NUM_ITER` x 15) where each row contains the value of `u` for that iteration.

Comment: This works! Thank you @jedwards. Sorry for the late reply. I was testing the code.